# From new google play guideline policies, does it mean developers have to create everything by themselves?

Tags: android, google-play

There are some things I seem not to understand from new google play guide polices and especially when it comes to  policy strike such as violating the impersonation policy. Now does it mean developers should no longer download icons, drawable images e.t.c from the internet? Should app assets and drawable contain files created by developers themselves? Should app names be unique as per new google play policy guidelines?

Comment: Interesting questions, but I voted to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic